Reboot issue with Checkway and OpenSUSE
I installed OpenSUSE 15.6 from scratch on Checkway POS ChwaySH-J, but it hangs on system reboot.
I mention interesting point. When I choose Exit or Reboot menu item from installer USB before system is installed, it rebooting. But it can not reboot after installation...
I removed splash=silent and quiet from grub and these are last lines on the screen while system is rebooting:
Reached target System Shutdown
Reached target Late Shutdown Service
Finished System Reboot
Reached target System Reboot

Also I add Storage=persistent to journald and this is tail of journalctl -b -1:
systemd[1537]: Stopped target Main User Target.
systemd[1537]: Stopped target Basic System.
systemd[1537]: Stopped target Paths.
systemd[1537]: Stopped target Sockets.
systemd[1537]: Stopped target Timers.
systemd[1537]: Stopped Daily Cleanup of User's Temporary Directories.
systemd[1537]: Closed D-Bus User Message Bus Socket.
systemd[1537]: Stopped Create User Files and Directories.
systemd[1537]: Removed slice User Application Slice.
systemd[1537]: Reached target Shutdown.
systemd[1537]: Finished Exit the Session.
systemd[1537]: Reached target Exit the Session.

I installed system as ext4. Grub is just Grub2 (not EFI). BIOS configured by default:

Default for Legacy and EFI
Default for ACMP

May by I need to rewrite kernel module for reboot and make it same as in USB installer? Or the issue can be solved with reconfiguration of some thing?
UPDATE
Here is cpuinfo:
prog@posopensusemp:~> cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep processor
processor       : 0
processor       : 1
processor       : 2
processor       : 3
prog@posopensusemp:~> cat /proc/cpuinfo | head -n 27
processor       : 0
vendor_id       : GenuineIntel
cpu family      : 6
model           : 55
model name      : Intel(R) Celeron(R) CPU  J1900  @ 1.99GHz
stepping        : 9
microcode       : 0x90d
cpu MHz         : 2416.845
cache size      : 1024 KB
physical id     : 0
siblings        : 4
core id         : 0
cpu cores       : 4
apicid          : 0
initial apicid  : 0
fpu             : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level     : 11
wp              : yes
flags           : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology tsc_reliable nonstop_tsc cpuid aperfmperf tsc_known_freq pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm sse4_1 sse4_2 movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer rdrand lahf_lm 3dnowprefetch epb pti ibrs ibpb stibp tpr_shadow flexpriority ept vpid tsc_adjust smep erms dtherm ida arat vnmi md_clear
vmx flags       : vnmi preemption_timer invvpid ept_x_only flexpriority tsc_offset vtpr mtf vapic ept vpid unrestricted_guest
bugs            : cpu_meltdown spectre_v1 spectre_v2 mds msbds_only mmio_unknown
bogomips        : 4000.00
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 36 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:

I added nolapic option to Grub - it works, but system recognized just on CPU core. noapic option didn't work.
